# How to place Mirelurk Observer in Fallout 3

Tags: fallout-3

I am trying to complete the 2nd (I think) chapter quest for Moira's Wasteland survival book, but I am having trouble placing the observer in Mirelurk nest.

I travel to the right place and locate some Mirelurk nest/eggs, but when I try to transfer some items into the nest, the observer is not displayed in my pip-boy so i can't transfer it across. However, when I walk away and look at my pip-boy I can see the observer.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you reach the place marked on your map open the egg clutch-container - it is the nest on the lowest level of the Anchorage Memorial. Then you should browse your inventory and manually place the Observer into the clutch - mission complete.

Maybe the description of "Fallout.wikia" can help you

> The easiest and quickest nest to get to without confrontation of a single Mirelurk is the nest located behind the locked [Very Easy] door due southwest from the entrance to Tepid Sewers. After entering, make the first right turn. Directly ahead will be an egg pod. Place the observer and run out.

Stealth Boys are the best choice to reach the optional goal ;)

Comment: I've completed this quest a few times without Stealth and without killing any Mirelurks.  You just run as fast as you can, dodging around obstacles to avoid getting hit by the Mirelurks.  It's only hard in the sense that you have to keep your itchy trigger finger under control.

Comment: I completed the quest by having been there before so no Mirelurks could accidentally be killed... (I did _not_ know of this quest then, I just felt like exploring) That counted as reaching the optional goal as well

Answer (score -2):

I know this is years after the game was released but I'm finally playing through it and you can place the observer on the first level in any of the egg clutches hidden behind closed doors before you get into the memorial itself.